# Not Getting all results of other field in a table if one of the field is grouped by

Tags: php, mysql

I am grouping the model field in cars table ,but i am  getting only  one,one  result ,istead of all , from  each differend grouped by  models.

suppose there are three 1990,19190,1990 under moldel field and three cars suzuki,honda,tyota are undel car_name whose model is 1990 .but I am getting results of  only one car name  under 1990 model.   Plz help me.

```
         $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars group by  model ");
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
       $car_name=$row['car_name'];
       $model=$row['model'];


            ?>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td><?php  echo $model ?></td>   //here is displaying  1990.

        </tr >
        <tr  >
              <td> <?php   echo $car_name;  ?></td>    // but here is displayed only onr car name istead of all.

        </tr>

    </table>



    <?php

      }
```

Comment: Don't they all appear in 3 separate tables ?

Comment: Why do you put `GROUP BY model` in your SQL?  Was there something wrong with the results of a query without that clause?

Comment: @eggyal i grouped by model field to avoid dispalying the duplicate resuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you group by a particular column, you are asking for just one row for each value of that column. If you want 1990 Honda and also 1990 Suzuki, you should use `GROUP BY car_name, model` to get all the unique combinations of this pair of columns.

BTW, does your model column contain years? Car models are names like Accord, Camry, Celica.

EDIT:

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT model, GROUP_CONCAT(car_name)
FROM cars
GROUP BY model
```

Comment: thanks,i dont want the repetation of car models ,also want o get all the results relted of a model

Comment: ,thank u so much.it worked.but i am geeting car name as "honda,toyota,suzuki"--that means names with commas inside.how can name be displayed like as a list.i used <br> tag ,but it did not work.thnks

Answer (score -1):

i believe that should work

```
<table>
  <?php 
     /* use this if doing process elimination. 
      $q = '1990';
      $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE model = '$q' "); 
    */
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE ORDER By model ASC ");
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {  ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php  echo $row['model']; ?></td>   //here is displaying  1990.

        </tr >
        <tr  >
              <td> <?php   echo $row['car_name'];  ?></td>    // but here is displayed only onr car name istead of all.

        </tr>
 <?php     }      ?>
    </table>
```